# Python - Получить параметры из url (callback)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, callback

Есть "web страница" на python размещенная на хостинге. пример "url/main.py"

На страницу приходит POST запрос

```
{ "type": "confirmation", "group_id": 15265498 }
```

Как получить данные POST запроса?

Comment: "Как получить данные POST запроса?" На страницу приходит POST запрос { "type": "confirmation", "group_id": 15265498 }. Что не так? А где ваш код?

Comment: Кода нет т.к это первое что надо сделать, а я не знаю как обработать входящий callback с параметрами чтобы обработать эти параметры и дать ответ серверу который послал POST запрос/

Comment: Зависит от того, как реализована ваша "web страница". Какая там библиотека используется? В зависимости от существующей реализации, это будет делаться очень по разному.

Comment: как вы получили входящий callback?